# Freeform Element Connections to Update Existing Entries

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I have a Freeform 3 form and I have mapped it to an existing channel. The connection works, and filling out a form creates a new entry, but it only create new entries. The form is on an entry page. The channel has an autogenerated Title and I am pulling that into the form template via a hidden field.

I was hoping to be able to "update" **existing entries** and not just create new ones. Do I need to also pull in the entry.slug or entry.id? Or do the element connections not have this functionality?

What I am getting is only new entries: entry-01, entry-02, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Freeform docs](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v3/overview/element-connections.html#editing-elements) it looks like you'll need to pass an element ID.

> Freeform allows you to edit/update existing Craft elements (Entries, Users and Calendar Events currently) by including the elementId parameter in your form. It works by feeding a Freeform form an element ID.

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("editCraftUsers").render({
    elementId: currentUser.id
}) }}
```

The docs have more details on the exact options.